# copying certain portion of data from contst char * array into another const char * array

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++

I am able to copy some data  from char array  into another char array in a loop. For example I want to extract and display each 2 characters of char array into `b`. But it doesn't work with `const char *`. Can anyone please suggest me why its not working with `const char *`. Actually I need to do this with `const char*`.

```
char array[] = "HelloRamBilasj";

cout << "total length of array buffer:" << strlen(array) << endl << endl;
int totalGoLength= strlen(array)/2 ; //divide by number of elements you want to display in one loop

cout << "required length of alice buffer:" << totalGoLength << endl << endl;

int oneGoCount=1;
int start=0;//starting index to copy
int next=2;//end index to copy

while( oneGoCount <= totalGoLength) {

    char *b = new char[100];
    // now copy the elemet into b.
    std::copy(array+start, array+next, b);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i){
        cout<< "the value of b is"<<b[i]<<endl;

    }
    cout<<endl<<endl;

    delete [] b;//erase the contents of b.
    start=start+2;//increment the next index
    next=next+2;//increment the next index

    oneGoCount=oneGoCount+1;

}//end of while
```

Comment: When the target is another `const char*` what makes you think you're allowed writing there?

Comment: If you are writing C++, drop the C tag and start using `std::string` and get rid of that `new`.

Comment: Please don't use keywords or language features that you don't know what they are good for...

Answer (score 7):

You cannot change tha data a `const char*` points to because the data it points to is `const`.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can copy from a const char *, but not into a const char *.
```

As per the rules, **the variables declared with const qualifier cannot be modified**, and
when you copy into such a variable then you are attempting to modify the
contents of that memory location and thus you will get a compile time error as under :

```
assignment of read-only location
```